# What is the name of a person who runs and manages a game?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for the term that describes a person who is in charge of managing the games (not judging, but for example, spreading the cards in card games...)

Comment: The person who deals (distributes) the cards is the dealer, but this isn't necessarily the same person in every game.

Answer (score 3):

In many settings you would be talking about a *tournament director*. Such a person is responsible for ensuring that all the games in a tournament are able to go ahead. Some specific games require people to manage the game play, such as a spinner in two up, a dungeon master in Dungeons & Dragons, a croupier or a dealer in many casino games, and various others. The titles for these people depend on the game concerned.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to describe a person who does this as their job in a casino, you might be looking for the word [croupier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/croupier) or dealer.

The manager of a casino section (sort of the supervisor for a group of croupiers) is called a [pit boss or pit manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_manager).